How to prove that element $\varepsilon$ exists in SDG?
In SDG/SIA there is field (Smooth real line) and element $\varepsilon$, $\varepsilon$ satisfy $\varepsilon^2=0$ but it's proved that $\varepsilon$ is not element of a field.
I spent much time to find how to prove that element $\varepsilon$ exists but I didn't find proof (I searched in many sources).
SDG uses intuitionistic logic but it doesn't prove that element $\varepsilon$ exists.
My question is: How to prove that element $\varepsilon$ exists in SDG?
Thanks.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
